# Marketing Cloud - Close Window in cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

What methods do we have in Marketing Cloud to close the current cloudpage window ?

In our usecase, the customers click on button inside an email which takes them to a cloud page.

After they entered the data in the cloud page, I would like to present an option to them to close the current cloud page.

Is there an option to close the current cloud page (similar to "`window.close()`" JS method) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in Cloud Pages which prevents you from using JavaScript as you would do on other HTML pages. However, browsers prevent you from closing windows with javascript that were not opened with `window.open("https://example.com")`. So when you open a page from a link in an email, you won't be able to use JavaScript to close that window again.